# How do I prove the following fact about non constant complex polynomials?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials

I have the following problem:

> Given a polynomial $f(z)=z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_1z+a_0$. I need to show that there exists $R>0$ such that $$|f(z)|\geq \frac{|z|^n}{2}$$ for $|z|\geq R$.

I somehow got a bit stuck because I tried many different ways without getting on the right path. My first problem is to compute the absolut value of $f$ such that it gets smaller.

Thus I wanted to ask if you could help me here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You have to assume $,|a_n|>1/2.$

Comment: sorry there was a mistake. I corrected it. Could I now simply say that for $z\rightarrow \infty$ we have $\left|\frac{f(z)}{z^n}\right|=1\geq \frac{1}{2}$ or isn't this enough?

Comment: Yes, it suffices to observe that $$\lim_{|z|\to \infty }{|f(z)|\over |z|}=1$$ and $1>1/2.$

Comment: ah wow perfect thanks!

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\vert f(z)\vert = \vert z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 z + a_0 \vert\\
\\
\geq \vert z\vert ^n - \left( \vert a_{n-1} \vert \vert z^{n-1} \vert + \ldots + \vert a_1 \vert \vert z \vert + \vert a_0 \vert \right) \\
\\
\geq \vert z\vert ^n - M n \vert z\vert^{n-1},\ \text{where } M = \max\{\ \vert a_{n-1} \vert,\ \vert a_{n-2} \vert,\ \ldots,\ \vert a_1 \vert,\ \vert a_0 \vert\}; \\
\\
\geq \frac{\vert z\vert^n}{2} \iff \frac{\vert z\vert^n}{2} \geq M  n\vert z\vert^{n-1} \iff \vert z \vert \geq 2Mn. \\
\end{align}

In conclusion, $\vert f(z)\vert \geq \frac{\vert z\vert^n}{2}$ if $\vert z \vert \geq 2Mn\ $ and whilst in general this is not the least upper bound, it is always an upper bound, which is all we require for the question asked...